# How to achieve this in my iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

[image]

How to get above thing in my application?

What is this? I don't know what we call this type of thing can any one guide me for this and the technical term of this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: In traditional computing, it's called a *modal dialog*. On iOS, you might call it something slightly different.

Comment: There is no technical term for this. This is extremely custom UI written specifically for this app, and if you have to ask how to do it, then, no offense meant, but you won't be able to do it. Unless you're just asking how to have a modal dialog, at which point I'd say use the modal dialog APIs. But if you mean the gesture to pull it out and unfold it, etc, you can't do it.

Comment: I have a feeling that he wants to know how to get to that... I say in the Twitter app you just pick a user and then pinch it out with two your two fingers... Although that really is a question that does not belong in this site =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use one view controller to present another view controller modally on top of it.

```
[currentViewController presentModalViewController:viewControllerToPresentInModalWindow
                                         animated:YES];
```

By default, the modal view controller will be full-screen, but you can change the size to one of two other presets.

```
[viewControllerToPresentInModalWindow setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];

[viewControllerToPresentInModalWindow setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
```

Additionally, you can set the transition used to display the modal window on screen by using `setModalTransitionStyle:`.

The screenshot posted above is not using any of these presets; as the other commenters mentioned, it is a custom modal window that doesn't leverage UIKit's built-in modal functionality.